# Where can I see the Floodlight code in the solution

Tags: c#, html, google-tag-manager, google-floodlight

I am seeing the following comment in the browser on inspecting the page elements, but I do not know where this code is coming from.
I am not finding this in my solution.I want to remove this comment, Could some one please let me know how I can do that.

Here goes the commented code from my page :

```
<!--
Start of DoubleClick Floodlight Tag: Please do not remove
Activity name of this tag: Site1 - Dual Brand - Support - Tools - S JS
URL of the webpage where the tag is expected to be placed: https://site2.com
This tag must be placed between the <body> and </body> tags, as close as possible to the opening tag.
Creation Date: 07/28/2014
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are HTML comments that are included by default when generating Floodlight tags from the DoubleClick system. If you believe the Floodlight tag is being deployed through GTM, look through the Custom HTML tags in your container for the code.